# Using gdal_translate in node-gdal?

Tags: gdal-translate, node-js

How can I use gdal_translate in node-gdal?

I'm trying to use the following command:

```
gdal_translate C:\test.tif cog.tif -co TILED=YES -co COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE.
```

Comment: Do you have GDAL available at all? Does `gdalinfo --version` show anything?

Comment: What do you mean if I have gdal available? I can get some infos about a tif etc. but I can’t figured it out how to do the same with this package as I can do with OsGeo command shell.

Comment: Not so well formulated question but you seem to have working node java bindings. I have no experience on coding with node. Perhaps the links here help https://github.com/naturalatlas/node-gdal/issues/216 but you must write some code "node-gdal has all the pieces needed to do everything gdal_translate does – you will just have to create the dataset, set the geoTransform, read and write the data, etc yourself."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node-gdal` does not come with GDAL's CLI tools.

The only version of `node-gdal` that supports `gdal_translate` and does so as the library call `gdal.translate()` is `node-gdal-async`

(Disclaimer: I am the author of `node-gdal-async`)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @mmomtchev answer you may have a look [here](https://mmomtchev.github.io/node-gdal-async/#:%7E:text=src/gdal_utils.cpp-,Library%20version%20of%20gdal_translate.,-Parameters)
make sure that you add each command line argument you use is a separate element of the argument array.
Example:

```
const ds = gdal.open('input.tif')
const out = gdal.translate('/vsimem/temp.tif', ds, [ '-b', '1' ])
```

'-b' and '1' are separate

this should also apply in other languages, I'm using c# and it follows the same way.